# recover whatsapp conversation after hard reset

Tags: samsung, whatsapp-messenger, data-recovery, 7.0-nougat

i just installed nougat on my galaxy s7 forgetting to backup whatsapp conversations.
Now is all blank,sd and memory, can i recover them?

Comment: If you didn't back up to drive, you can't

Answer (score 0):

The new feature of WhatsApp allows users to take backup in Google Drive. There are chances that you will be able to Restore your backup from Google Drive.

Comment: no backup on google drive...i just need to dig in the memory or sd to take it back, but which app or which software?

Comment: The backup folder is hidden in the Google Drive. Just try to open your WhatsApp and give a try or else you can also use WA Tweaks on your rooted phone to have a look at your chats